# CASE statement with IN in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, where-clause

I'm trying to create the following WHERE clause:

```
AND CASE @SomePRarmeter
WHEN 'this' THEN
  user_id IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.func_Id1(@User))
WHEN 'that' THEN
  user_id IN (SELECT user_id from dbo.func_Ids2(@OrgsForReporter)
END
```

But I'm getting an error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN' (in the first condition) , although separately both of those conditions work. What would be the correct way to make such a statement work?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried putting parentheses around the 3rd and 5th lines?

Comment: Like that -       (user_id IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.func_getReportsToUserId(@User)))? It didn't work either, gave me the same error about IN and then about ')'

Comment: NM my last comment. The THEN clause expects a value. The IN expression doesn't evaluate to a value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
AND (
  (@SomePRarmeter = 'this' AND user_id IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.func_Id1(@User)))
  OR
  (@SomePRarmeter = 'that' AND user_id IN user_id IN (SELECT user_id from dbo.func_Ids2(@OrgsForReporter)))
)
```

Comment: +1 Much better than a complicated case!  Perhaps change the `select *` into `select user_id` (though it shouldn't matter if the function returns only one column)

Answer (score 2):

You are doing select * in a subquery.  You need to return only one column:

```
(SELECT * FROM dbo.func_Id1(@User))
```

to this:

```
(SELECT YOUR_USER_ID_COLUMN FROM dbo.func_Id1(@User))
```

Comment: the return table has one column, and I changed it to the name, but it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

A case statement must result in a value, not an expression.  So this won't work:

```
select case when 1=1 then 1 in (1,2,3) end
```

But this will work;

```
select case when 1=1 then 1 end
```

The value can be the result of a subquery.  So one solution would be to rewrite the `where` clause like:

```
CASE @SomePRarmeter
WHEN 'this' THEN
  (SELECT count() FROM dbo.func_Id1(@User) f where f.user_id = t.user_id))
WHEN 'that' THEN
  (SELECT count() from dbo.func_Ids2(@OrgsForReporter) f where f.user_id = t.user_id))
END > 1
```

Now it returns the number of matching rows.  You can then filter with `case ... end > 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd break this out:

```
IF 'this'
    SELECT 
    ...
    WHERE user_id IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.func_Id1(@User))
ELSE IF 'that'
    SELECT
    ...
    WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id from dbo.func_Ids2(@OrgsForReporter))
```

Comment: The query is huge, i wouldn't like to rewrite it just because of this clause, but thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`CASE ... END` returns an expression, not a piece of literal SQL code. Rather than:

```
AND CASE foo WHEN bar THEN bla=ble END -- Wrong
```

... you have to use this:

```
AND bla = CASE foo WHEN bar THEN ble END -- Right
```

In your case, you can do something on this line:

```
-- Untested
AND  (
    (@SomePRarmeter='this' AND user_id IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.func_Id1(@User)))
    OR (@SomePRarmeter='that' AND user_id IN (SELECT user_id from bo.func_Ids2(@OrgsForReporter))
)
```